# Potting Multiple Graphs Using Plotly JS

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, graph, plotly

I am trying to plot 4 graphs in one single div, where in first plot multiple Y axis will be there and in second plot 2 y axis will come and in third plot single Y axis and fourth is again 2 y axis.

Can anyone please suggest is there any better way to do it using Plotly JS?

I have referred few links, but they are all single graph. but I am looking for 4 plots with different y axis.

URL: https://plotly.com/javascript/multiple-axes/#multiple-yaxes

Attached an image, my result should look something like the image

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

For your problem statement Plotly JS provides subplots. The documentation of Plotly javascript subplots is available at [Subplots in Plotly JavaScript](https://plotly.com/javascript/subplots/)

You can create multiple subplots and manage layouts of the plot.
Here is the sample code for plotting suubplots

```
    var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3],
  y: [4, 5, 6],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [20, 30, 40],
  y: [50, 60, 70],
  xaxis: 'x2',
  yaxis: 'y2',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  grid: {rows: 1, columns: 2, pattern: 'independent'},
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

The sample graph looks like this
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyybQ.png)